# Blown save when starter is ineligible for a win

Tags: baseball, statistics, mlb, scoring

I'm parsing some baseball data, so I need to be able to appropriately award saves, blown saves, holds, etc. In doing so, I came across some examples that I'm unsure how to handle.

**Example 1:** Suppose Adam is the starter and he leaves the game after 4 innings and his team is leading by a run. Billy comes in and pitches into the 8th, when he gives up the tying run. **Is Billy charged with a blown save?**

**Example 2:** Suppose pitcher Adam is the starter and he leaves the game after 4 innings and his team is leading by a run. Billy comes in and pitches a scoreless 5th and 6th. The score is unchanged when Charlie comes in in the 7th, and allows the tying run. **Is Charlie charged with a blown save?**

**Example 3:** Suppose pitcher Adam is the starter and he leaves the game after 4 innings and his team is leading by a run. Billy comes in and pitches a scoreless 5th. The score is unchanged when Charlie comes in in the 6th, and he pitches a scoreless 6th, 7th, and 8th. It is still a 1 run game when David comes in in the 9th, and records a scoreless 9th. **Could the official scorer determine that Charlie deserves the win (hence David gets a save), while Billy gets a hold?**

**My intuition:** 1) No, because there is no other pitcher eligible to receive the win. Hence, it's not truly a save situation, and Billy can't be charged with a blown save. 2) Yes, because Billy could be assigned the win, thus Charlie would have entered in a save situation. Therefore, he would be charged with a blown save. 3) No, it doesn't make any sense for a pitcher to get a hold and the pitcher that relieves him gets a win when their team does not surrender their lead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All rules related with [Win-loss record (pitching)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Win%E2%80%93loss_record_(pitching)), [Save (baseball)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Save_(baseball)) and [Hold (baseball)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hold_(baseball)) are well-explained in the links. Your questions seem to be focused on save situations.

1. No. In order for a pitcher to be credited with a save or charged with a blown save, there should be a save situation (opportunity). Since there is none, Billy will not be charged with a blown save.
2. Yes.
3. Yes or no.  If Charlie was the most effective relief pitcher **in the official scorer's judgment**, he could be awarded a win. Also, you need to note that David can't get a hold because there was no save situation.

> A save is a statistic credited to a
>   relief pitcher, as set forth in Rule 10.19 of the Official Rules of
>   Major League Baseball. That rule states the official scorer shall
>   credit a pitcher with a save when such pitcher meets all four of the
>   following conditions:
>
> 1. He is the finishing pitcher in a game won by his team;
> 2. He is not the winning pitcher;
> 3. He is credited with at least 1/3 of an inning pitched; and He satisfies one of the following conditions:
>
>    (1) He enters the game with a lead of no more than three runs and pitches for at least one inning
>
>    (2) He enters the game, regardless of the count, with the potential tying run either on base, at bat or on deck
>
>    (3) He pitches for at least three innings.
>
> If a relief pitcher satisfies all of the criteria for a save, except he does not finish
>   the game, he will often be credited with a hold (which is not an
>   officially recognized statistic by Major League Baseball).

Comment: In your answer, under E1, I assume you mean Billy? And my instinct (no one else can get a win implies that a save situation doesn't exist) is correct? Similarly, in E3, David would get a save by virtue of closing the game (assuming he's not named the winner). I fail to see how E2 and E3 could be "yes or no, it depends" type of answers. I would expect them to be one or the other. If in E1 Billy cannot be charged with a blown save, because there was no one else eligible for a win, then I would expect that in E2 Charlie would be charged with a blown save, because Billy could get the win.

Comment: @PistolPete I edited my answer.

Comment: thanks for clearing up the confusion. Additionally, my reasoning that I gave at the end of my initial post is correct?